# jquery select class but not id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, prop

This is strange for me when I choose an element by `id` ; jquery code does not work , but when I choose it  by `classname` it works great !

this code :

```
<input name='daneshjou_number' class='daneshjou_number'  type='text'  >
```

this code works :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".is_daneshjou").change(function(){
        //alert("The text has been changed.");
        $(".daneshjou_number").prop('readonly', true);
    });
});
    </script>
```

but this code does not work :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".is_daneshjou").change(function(){
        //alert("The text has been changed.");
        $("#daneshjou_number").prop('readonly', true);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Because element doesn't have an `ID` Attribute!

Comment: where is the `id` attribute in `<input name='daneshjou_number' class='daneshjou_number'  type='text'  >`?

Comment: oh my god ; I had not seen it :))  I  was searchinfg in jquery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should give your `input`  id :

```
<input id='daneshjou_number' name='daneshjou_number' class='daneshjou_number'  type='text' />
```

in your jquery code your calling `#daneshjou_number`  but there is not any element with this specefic id ib your code

Answer (score 2):

You don't have id for the element, you have name and class

```
<input id='daneshjou_number' name='daneshjou_number' class='daneshjou_number'  type='text'  >
```

Comment: oh my god ; I had not seen it :))

Answer (score 0):

No `id` for element.

```
<input id='daneshjou_number' name='daneshjou_number' class='daneshjou_number'  type='text' />
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery `.` is used to identify classes and `#` for ids. You need to have an attribute named `id` in your HTML code.

```
    <input id='daneshjou_number' class='daneshjou_number' type='text'  >
```